# How to make autofocus by angular 7 on click a button

Tags: html, angular

I have some text box in a table coming from loop.Initially those text boxes are disabled,after click edit button it will be enabled.Till now working fine.But I want to make auto focus in first textbox of first row when I click on edit button.I tried with autofocus attribute but its not working.Can anyone please help me on it.Here is the code below

### app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Basic Table</h2>
    <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>
    <div><button (click)="enable()">Edit</button> </div>
    <table class="table border">

        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index">
                <td> <input autofocus [disabled]='toggleButton' type="text" value="{{row.name}}"> </td>
                <td> <input [disabled]='toggleButton' type="text" value="{{row.items}}"> </td>
                <td> <button (click)="addRow(i)">Add</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    public toggleButton: boolean = true;
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  groups=[
     {
       "name": "pencils",
       "items": "red pencil"
     },
     {
       "name": "rubbers",
       "items": "big rubber"
     },
     {
       "name": "rubbers1",
       "items": "big rubber1"
     },
  ];
  addRow(index): void {
    var currentElement = this.groups[index];
    this.groups.splice(index, 0, currentElement);
 }
 enable(){
       this.toggleButton = false
    }
  //console.log(this.groups);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should @ViewChild decorator to select the first textbox and then use focus method of NativeElement to focus.
Note that setTimeout is used to to give execution time of boolean.

Working Example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-table-focus

Comment: Thanks for your answer can we put blue border in entire row for which textbox is focused.Suppose textbox of first row is focused so entire first row of table will be blue,again when we focus on any text box of second row entire second row of the table should be bordered..so on

Comment: I am getting this errror ----   ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(10,23): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ stat
ic: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ read?: any; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'static' does not exist
in type '{ read?: any; }'.

Comment: remove static: false from @ViewChild() or upgrade to angular 8

Comment: I think you should include the "core" of the codes in this answer (alongside with a link to stackblitz) in a case that the link may not be working in the future. Anw, it works like a charm, thanks.

Comment: @Anh-ThiDINH thanks for the suggestion. I will consider it next time.